# How to connect 111ager Solid State Relay with Arduino to control a 5VDC@2.1A load

Tags: solid-state-relay, optoelectronics

I just bought from ebay 111ager SSR 3-32VDC input power supply with load current upto 5A @ 5-220VDC. Link to the product: (https://goo.gl/MOkAU3).

I wanted to use it to control a 5VDC@2.1A load using Arduino UNO. I didn't connect any external component as I thought the SSR should do the task it is designed for without having to include external electrical components.

The code in the arduino puts high the SSR pin for 10 seconds and then turns it low for 5 seconds. I connected my smartphone (samsung galaxy S6) on the load side. And here is what happens: My phone just blinks without charging after each 5 second the SSR is LOW. The picture below shows the connection diagram.

[image]

My guess was that the phone is not getting enough current from the USB power supply as the SSR probably has higher resistance. But I don't know what I should do.  Any kind of comment/suggestion is quite welcome.

[PS: I connected the SSR input at 5V DC of the Arduino. The same things happens with the 3.3v of the arduino]

Look forward!

Comment: Show pictorially how you connected the load and please provide a proper data sheet link to the alleged solid state relay named as GJ-5FA-L on the product you linked.

Comment: also, please use a better title that describes your problem

Comment: Andy and Marcus, thanks for the feedback. This is my first post on the forum and I will improve in the future. I just could not find the datasheet for GJ-5FA-L on the internet. Some description can be found on the arduino forum (https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=231045.0)

Comment: looks like a perfect example of a **nefarious part**  . Mager Company register in China about 1 yr ago , has no website ( formerly WENZHOU TAICHUAN ELECTRIC CO., LIMITED registered www.tceele.com but never created), no legitimate specs and very little eng. credible information.   Observe these characteristics and recalibrate your judgement in future.

Comment: more nefarious info http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-Channel-SSR-Solid-State-Relay-High-low-Trigger-5A-3-32V-For-Arduino-Uno-R3-New/361423317029?_trksid=p2047675.c100623.m-1&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D38530%26meid%3Dfd20d9dce43e4f1ba1593afc0c5380f7%26pid%3D100623%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D331651616280 Trigger: high level trigger, 3-32VDC relay switches on (ON), **0-0.5V relay is switched off (OFF) 0.5-2.5 volts unknown state** does not look like SSR but fake relay specs.. try 12V

Answer (score 1):

If the rough specifications that are available for the relay are correct, then it is not suitable for your task.

- ON the relay image on the site you quote the usable voltage range is shown as 5-220 VDC.
- This stack exchange question and answer from 2014 [Arduino SSR 5V DC (Mager GJ-3FA-L)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/105306/3288) indicates tat the relay is for use with 5V-220VDC and has a typically 2.5 VDC dro on the load side when on.

So - you are trying to use the relay with a voltage that is higher than the minimum allowed by the USB spec (ie 5V). Designs MUST ALWAYS use worst case specifications.

Even if it worked at USB vltages, the 2.5V drop wil make it completely unsuited to your application.

Measuring the on-voltage-drop with a meter will allow you to better determine the actual drop.

Metallic contact relays are still, in many cases, and apparently including this one. a better solution than are SSRs. Alas.

You could make a switch that met your need using a suitable MOSFET and perhaps an optocoupler if you need good isolation.

Comment: Hi Russell: Do you mean electromechanical relays by metallic contact relays? I have used them and they work fine. It is just that I worried they might tear down easily. I also bought  FOD3184V optocouplers but didn't succeed in making it work.

Comment: @maranatha  you must specify DC ohm resistance or peak current, you may need a 10A relay to handle surge . Just use a 10~20A MOSFET Pch

Comment: @maranatha Yes. Metallic contact relays. Still very good in many applications. As Tony says - a MOSFET is a good solution given a suitable circuit.

Comment: @Tony Do you have any MOSFET model that you suggest? It would be really helpful.

Comment: @Russel, I had a 3A optocoupler (FOD3184). But this did not also switch on my load.  Do I have to look for an optocoupler with higher current rating? What is really key thing to consider when buying an optocoupler for 2.1A@5VDC load?

Comment: @maranatha  there are a million MOSFET parts to choose from.  If you know the surge current rating of the load, and wish to not use a heat sink then the voltage drop should be small for this surge current. The optimum depends on your budget, package type TH or SMD, RdsOn, Vmax and duty cycle of switching the load for surges. You should choose only "logic level" types for gate drive for Vgs http://ca.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Discrete-Semiconductors   /_/N-awhng?Keyword=pc+mosfet&FS=True  or https://goo.gl/9gqVZG

Comment: The FOD3184 is an IGBT rated for 3A but has 1 Ohm ESR output

Comment: @Tony Thank you very much for the information. I will have to admit that I haven't considered many of the things you mentioned. Could you elaborate a bit about the thing you said "You should choose only "logic level" types for gate drive for Vgs"? How accurate can I measure the surge current of my load using a regular multi-meter?

Comment: What is the load?

Comment: I am considering to buy this relay switch from sparkfun, do you  think it will control my load?  https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13815

Comment: @maranatha That relay will be easily able to do what you want - but is "overkill" - it can handle much more current that needed and takes 150 mA from the 5V supply to operate it. The circuit diagram is [**here**](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/SparkFun_Beefcake_Relay_Control_Kit_v20a.pdf) An indentical circuit but with a lower current relay would do as well for your application. | On ebay there are many 5V relay modules. You want ones which will operate from a 5V (or 3v3) logic input. [**Many examples here**](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/5v-relay)

Comment: @maranatha   eg [**this relay**](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5V-1-2-4-8-Channel-Relay-Board-Module-Optocoupler-LED-for-Arduino-PiC-ARM-AVRC-/311672067486) and offers selection of 1 2 4 or 8 channels - price is a bargain - IF quality is OK. $US1.25 and free shipping for single channel (1 relay)!  $US4.85 for 8 relay module. These have logic drive and low current operation. I have used a number of similar ones. Excellent at low loadings - I'd be wary of using then for switching mains.

Comment: @maranatha | [**Even cheaper - 99.6% feedback](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5V-1-2-4-8-Channel-Relay-Board-Module-Optocoupler-LED-for-Arduino-PiC-ARM-AVRC-/172356149617)

Comment: @maranatha The relay you show should work PERFECTLY and the Sparkfun one should NOT be any better. If the relay turns off during bootup then something is probably affecting EITHER the drive signal or the power to the relay or the power to the Pi. You need to be CERTAIN that thse 3 things are OK. If they are and the relay is not faulty then it will not be the relay circuit that is faulty. | Can you hear the relay "click" when it operates and releases? (May be VERY quiet) Does it do this during booting. If it 'clicks' during boot there is a drive or relay power problem.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I can here the "click" sound when the relay switches on/off. One thing I made sure is that the driving signal to switch OFF/ON the relay doesn't change during the boot up time. So, it is probably the power to the relay or the power to the Pi. Is there something I could do to check which one of these two is actually affecting? I used Lithium battery house 5V@2.1A to power the Pi and 3v3 volt from the arduino to power the Pi

Comment: @maranatha An LED on the power supply concerned will flick if power is lost briefly - but a very brief flick may be missed. A relay coil should have a reverse diode across it to absorb turn off inductive spikes. As seen on the [Sparkfun schematic](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/SparkFun_Beefcake_Relay_Control_Kit_v20a.pdf) . Should not be needed on turn on. Capacitors of 100 uF or higher on power suipply rails near equipment are also 'useful'.